# AWS Lambda Function insert csv to ElasticSearch

Tags: python, csv, elasticsearch, aws-lambda

So i'm trying to insert some basic .csv files directly from a S3 bucket to elastic Search, each time a .csv will be dropped into the S3 it'll trigger my lambda that will feed the data from the .csv to Elastic Search, here's what i got so far :

```
import json
import os
import logging
import boto3
from datetime import datetime
import re
import csv
from aws_requests_auth.aws_auth import AWSRequestsAuth
from elasticsearch import RequestsHttpConnection, helpers, Elasticsearch
from core_libs.dynamodbtypescasters import DynamodbTypesCaster
from core_libs.streams import EsStream, EsClient

credentials = boto3.Session().get_credentials()

AWS_REGION = 'eu-west-3'
HOST = MY_PERSONAL_COMPANY_HOST
ES_SERVER = f"https://{HOST}"

AWS_ACCESS_KEY = credentials.access_key
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = credentials.secret_key
AWS_SESSION_TOKEN = credentials.token
 
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
     
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    awsauth = AWSRequestsAuth(
        aws_access_key=AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
        aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
        aws_token=AWS_SESSION_TOKEN,
        aws_host=HOST,
        aws_region=AWS_REGION,
        aws_service='es',
    )       
    
    BUCKET_NAME = record['s3']['bucket']['name']
    SOURCE_PATH = record['s3']['object']['key']
    SOURCE_FILE = SOURCE_PATH.split('/')[-1]
    
    obj = s3.get_object(Bucket=BUCKET_NAME, Key=SOURCE_PATH)
    body = obj['Body'].read()
    lines = body.splitlines()
   
    for line in lines:
        print(line)
```

And this is where i'm stuck. don't know if i should use the bulk API and if i can just insert a json version of my .csv as it is, nor how to do so

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer on you specific question.

However I am wondering why you are not using an SQS setup with Filebeat (recommended/out of the box functionality) and use an ingest pipeline with CSV processor?

Comment: The sales team is supposed to just drop their .csv in a specific bucket and the data "magically" appears in Kibana, so i need the lambda and the trigger

Comment: That is what happens when you use an SQS queue (notification from S3 of file being dropped) and Filebeat reading and using ingest pipelines.